# Unable to connect to the remote server - Facebook Api

Tags: facebook, api, exception

I am currently developing an application that uses the facebook api to get the posts from my feed.

I tested it locally using Visual Studio 2013 and it works just fine !

But when I publish it at IIS 7 it doesnt work.. it throws an exception while invoking the method Get of Facebook Client.
This is the error:

Exception Message: Unable to connect to the remote server

StackTrace of exception:

at Facebook.HttpHelper.OpenRead()
   at Facebook.FacebookClient.Api(HttpMethod httpMethod, String path, Object parameters, Type resultType)
   at Facebook.FacebookClient.Get(String path, Object parameters, Type resultType)
   at FacebookProxy.WebUI.Default.LoadPosts(ControlCollection container, String upperPostId)

Maybe I need some special configuration on the IIS? 
Thanks alot in advance

EDIT: I managed to attach the process to debug while launching the website from the IIS, and this was the inner exception message:

Inner Exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 31.13.64.113:443

This only occurs while launching from my local IIS why? I already disabled all Firewall

Comment: On IIS the exception is thrown at this line:

client.Get(string.Format(path, Global.ApplicationSettings.AccessToken));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved, error on proxy. I need to open port at my network